# KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java while accessing SOAP web service in java

Tags: java, ksoap2

I have added the library "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar " 
but  i am getting below error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:1353) at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127) at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63) at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)


    private void getData()
    {
    String METHOD_NAME = "schedule.setschedule";

        String SOAP_ACTION = "urn:schedule#setschedule";

        String NAMESPACE = "urn:schedule";

        String URL = "http://96.30.19.40:8080/server.php?wsdl";

         try {
            SoapObject request=soap(METHOD_NAME,SOAP_ACTION,NAMESPACE,URL);
            System.out.println("suceess");
            System.out.println(request.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("fail1");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fail2");
        }
}

public static SoapObject soap(String METHOD_NAME, String SOAP_ACTION, String NAMESPACE, String URL) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); //set up request
        request.addProperty("iTopN", "5"); //variable name, value. I got the variable name, from the wsdl file!

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); //put all required data into a soap envelope

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);  //prepare request

        HttpTransport httpTransport = new HttpTransport(URL);  

        httpTransport.debug = true;  //this is optional, use it if you don't want to use a packet sniffer to check what the sent message was (httpTransport.requestDump)

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); //send request

        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse(); //get response
        return result;
     }
```

Comment: Do you have the jar file containing javax/microedition/io/Connector in your CLASSPATH?

Comment: COuld you please give me path for the jar so that iu can download and add in classpath. I was unable to get the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not have the correct [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar) package

Comment: I have added the library "ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar  " but now i am getting below error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:1353)
 at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:127)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
 at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)

Comment: Add this jar file kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar

Comment: I have added the jar kxml2-min-2.3.0.jar but still getting the same error ,don't why it is not taking the jar

Answer (score 1):

The correct download url for the project is here
http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse?tm=2

The direct url provided above is an old version. Read the instructions and download the complete bundle.